# Additional arguments in my php class

Tags: php, oracle, api, foreach

I'm trying to add a new variable (argument) `$sugg_only = false' to the get_lists method. Right now I'm pulling all my data based on if the user has a sign in token. This works fine and returns the array of data on their custom list.

What I'm trying to do is return stuff from their shopping_list_name if the Suggested column is set to `Y`. This way if they don't have a custom list it will pull a suggested list that we provide.

Here’s the full list of what’s in the table:

```
ID SHOPPING_LIST_NAME                                 S SEQUENCE
```

---

```
  1 test amnaik shopping list                          N
  2 bonner shopping list                               N
  3 793d7384fa4fa247d6fae07db104147d0a2dad6e           Y
  4 kj's shopping list                                 N
  5 kj's shopping list from 1384201636                 N
  6 kj's shopping list from 1384201659                 N
  7 kj's shopping list from 1384202055                 N
  8 kj's shopping list from 1384202089                 N
  9 kj's shopping list from 1385064064                 N
 10 kj's shopping list from 1385064145                 N
 11 kj's shopping list from 1385064150                 N
 12 kj's shopping list from 1385064257                 N
 13 kj's shopping list from 1385064825                 N
 14 kj's shopping list from 1385064857                 N
```

So, as you see, there’s just one (terribly named) shopping list that’s setup as a suggestion.

```
// Get a user's shopping lists
    public function get_lists($clobber = false, $sugg_only = false) {
        if ($this->UserShoppingList != null && !$clobber) {
            return $this->UserShoppingList;

    } else if ($this->get_sign_in_token()) {
        global $db;

        $vars = array();
        $vars[] = array(':i_sign_in_token', strtoupper($this->get_sign_in_token()));

        $rows = $db->get_function_ref_cursor('custom.japi_shopping_list.get_lists_for_shopper(:i_sign_in_token)', $vars);

        // Turn the rows into objects and get their items.
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $list = new UserShoppingList(null, $this->sign_in_token);
            $list->get_from_array($row);
            $list->get_items();
            $this->UserShoppingList[] = $list;
        }

        return $this->UserShoppingList;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

api page:

```
   if(!isset($_GET['token']) && !isset($_GET['suggested_only'])) {
        die('Must pass-in either a \'token\' or \'suggested_only\' flag');
    }

    if(isset($_GET['token'])) {
        $shopper = new Shopper($_GET['token'])
        or die('Could not instantiate a new Shopper from the \'token\' passed-in');

        $array = array();
        $shopper_lists = $shopper->get_lists(true);
        foreach ($shopper_lists as $list) {
             $array[] = $list->json();
        }

          echo json_encode($array);        
//        echo json_encode($shopper_lists);
    }
```

Will i likely be writing another `foreach` loop and just including whatever happens if $sugg_only is equal to TRUE??

add something like so to the bottom of my api page??:

```
if(isset($_GET['suggested_only']) && $_GET['suggested_only'] == 'true') 
    {


    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with arrays I'll usually favour array_key_exists('suggested_only', $_GET) over isset($_GET['suggested_only'])

If there's nothing really different with the execution of the data, just a difference in the data you are selecting, I'd put your statement at the TOP of the API page, not the bottom.

That way, your IF statement can define a flag for when you inevitably call $shopper->get_lists()

You could do something like this:

```
$suggestions = false;
$clobber = false;
if(isset($_GET['suggested_only']) && $_GET['suggested_only'] == 'true') 
{
    $suggestions = true;

}

...

$shopper_lists = $shopper->get_lists($clobber, $suggestions);
```

This way, you don't really duplicate code fetching the data you want.

HOWEVER

When it comes down to it, what if you add a whole series of types of lists to get.  You don't want to add a flag and another variable to your get_lists function.  It would become a mess.

It would be better to have a single variable like $_GET['type'], and switch it as follows:

```
switch($_GET['type'])
{
   case 'thingo':
       $shopper->get_lists('thingo');
       //Or you could use $shopper->get_thingo_list();
       break;
   case 'suggestion':
       $shopper->get_lists('suggestion');
       //Or you could use $shopper->get_suggestion_list();
       break;
   case 'list':
       $shopper->get_lists('list');
       //Or you could use $shopper->get_list();
       break;
   default:
       //No type exists here
   break;
}
```

Some people might suggest to just pass the $_GET variable straight to your function, but I always get a bit nervous doing that for security reasons.